# Multilevel Inheritance - Invoke Child Level New Method

Tags: c#, oop

In the below program, since `new` keyword is used in the derived class, I am expecting the output "C" but am getting the output as "A". Can some one please explain the reason behind this?

Also, I would like to know how to invoke `Foo` method declared in the class `C`.

```
class A
    {
        public void Foo()
        {
            Console.Write("A");
        }
    }
    class B : A
    {
        new void Foo()
        {
            Console.Write("B");
        }
    }
    class C : B
    {
        new void Foo()
        {
            Console.Write("C");
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        C c = new C();
        c.Foo();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C.Foo()` has no visibility on the private Foo you new'ed up inside C - it will call the public derived Foo from A.

```
class C : B
{
    public void Test()
    {
        // this has visibility on the private new'ed up method and can call it
        this.Foo();
    }

    // this is just a private method - it does NOT shadow the public one
    // "new" does nothing valuable here
    new void Foo()  
    {
        Console.Write("C");
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    C c = new C();
    c.Foo();      // calls the public visible derived A.Foo
    c.Test();     // this will call the "new"ed up C.Foo()
}
```

Output:

```
AC
```

You can call private methods only from inside the class they belong to - not from the outside (unless you put the call to the private one inside a public method - see `Test`).

Most of the time `new`-ing up a method (to me) is a code smell.

Comment: "Thanks for the explanation. It was an interview question, my focus was on inheritance correctness and I overlooked the access modifier. It makes sense now."

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `new` in this context prevents inheritance, i.e., it hides the inherited methods instead of providing a new implementation of them. There are only rare situations where you want to do this. Mainly for static members, since those can't be overridden.

The right way to inherit and possibly override methods is to make them virtual:

```cs
class A
{
    public virtual void Foo()
    {
        Console.Write("A");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override void Foo()
    {
        Console.Write("B");
    }
}

class C : B
{
    public override void Foo()
    {
        Console.Write("C");
    }
}
```

Now, your test will work as expected. It will even work if you assign the new C to variable typed as `A`:

```cs
A a = new C();
a.Foo();   // Prints: C
```

That being said, your `Foo` methods in `B` and `C` don't have a `public` modifier and are thus `private`. I.e., you can only access `A.Foo`, which is `public`, from the outside.